# ViewModel observer gets called on screen rotation

Tags: android

I need to implement something as when rotating the screen i need the favorite list of items to stay as they are and not to update the UI even if there was no change in the favorite list.
i couldnt find any solution for that...
this is my viewmodel code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class FavouritesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository,
    private val geoCoderRepository: GeoCoderRepository
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _mappedData = MutableLiveData<Resource<Map<String,String>>>()

    val mappedData :LiveData<Resource<Map<String,String>>> = _mappedData

    val favourites :LiveData<List<Favourites>> = weatherRepository.getAllFavourites()


    fun setfetchListOfCities(list:List<Favourites>){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _mappedData.postValue(Resource.loading())
            val celiusList = mutableMapOf<String,String>()
            for (city in list) {
                val geoResult = geoCoderRepository.cityToLongLat(city.city)
                if (geoResult.status is Success) {
                    val concated_lat_long =
                        "${geoResult.status.data!!.lat},${geoResult.status.data!!.long}"
                    val resultBody = weatherRepository.fetchWeather(concated_lat_long)
                    if (resultBody.status is Success) {
                        celiusList.put(city.city, resultBody.status.data!!.current.temp_c.toInt().toString() +":"+resultBody.status.data!!.location.localtime.split(" ")[1])
                    } else if(resultBody.status is Error) {
                        _mappedData.postValue(Resource.error(resultBody.status.message))
                    }
                } else if(geoResult.status is Error) {
                    _mappedData.postValue(Resource.error(geoResult.status.message))
                }
            }
            _mappedData.postValue(Resource.success(celiusList))
        }
    }
}
```

this is my fragment code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FavouritesFragment: Fragment() {

    private var binding : FavouritesFragmentBinding by autoCleared()

    //The two fragments(also in WeatherScreenFragment) will use the same ViewModel of WeatherScreenViewModel
    //if declaring by viewModels() that means that each fragment will have its own instance of the viewModel and they won't share data among them
    private val viewModel : FavouritesViewModel by viewModels()
    //private val viewModel : FavouritesViewModel by viewModels()
    private var undoCity=""
    var list:List<Favourites> = listOf()



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FavouritesFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.favourites.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            list = it
            viewModel.setfetchListOfCities(list)
        }

        viewModel.mappedData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            when(it.status){
                is Loading ->{
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = true
                }

                is Success ->{
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                    binding.favouritesRv.adapter = FavouritesAdapter(list,it.status.data!!,object : FavouritesAdapter.FavouriteListener{
                        override fun onFavouriteClick(city: String) {
                            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_favouritesFragment_to_weatherScreenFragment,bundleOf("fav_city" to city))
                        }
                    },requireContext())

                    binding.favouritesRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                }

                is Error -> {
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.status.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }



        //For the recyclerview -> Touch helper -> Deleting items when swiping left or right.
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
            override fun getMovementFlags(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ) = makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)

            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
//                val fav =(binding.favouritesRv.adapter as FavouritesAdapter).favouriteAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
//                undoCity = fav.city
//                Snackbar.make(binding.root,"Item Deleted!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                    .setAction("Undo"){
//                    viewModel.insertCity(Favourites(undoCity))
//                }.show()
//
//                viewModel.deleteFavourite(fav)
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(binding.favouritesRv)
    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.favorite_menu,menu)
        val historyItem = menu.findItem(R.id.history_icon)
        val homeItem = menu.findItem(R.id.home_btn_icon)
        val colorControlNormal = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white)

        // Set tint for the icons
        historyItem.icon?.let { DrawableCompat.setTint(it, colorControlNormal) }
        homeItem.icon?.let { DrawableCompat.setTint(it, colorControlNormal) }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.home_btn_icon){
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_favouritesFragment_to_homeScreenFragment)
        }
        else if(item.itemId== R.id.history_icon){
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_favouritesFragment_to_historyFragment)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

was trying to use Event as i have seen on some posts but that didnt work as well.